# How can I assign awk array to a bash array?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm given string "s=c=g++", "ipynb=py" where the last item e.g. "g++" & "py" means compiler and all items before the compiler mean extensions. What I want to do is to get all (extension : compiler) pairs into a bash dictionary. I'm trying to assign elements of an awk array to bash array so later I could iterate through that bash array and update my dictionary.

I'm trying to split given string using awk split and assign the result to a bash array named "extensions" and I don't know how to make this work correctly

```
 for item in "${array[@]}"
 do
     compiler=$(echo $item | awk '{split($item, a, "="); print a[length(a)]}' )
     extensions=($(echo $item | awk '{split($item, a, "="); for (i=1; i <= length(a); i++); print(a[i])}' ))
     unset extensions[-1] # delete compiler from extensions array, compiler already stored in variable
     for item in "${extensions[@]}"
     do                                                                                                  
       echo $item                                                                                 
     done                                                      
 done
```

here ${array[@]} is array of given strings.

Now I'm just trying to understand if it works and printing each item from extensions array, but it prints nothing and it's length is 0

Comment: What does the `$array` variable contain?

Comment: `split($item, a, "=")` looks wrong, Awk has no idea what `$item` is (inside Awk, it looks for an Awk variable `item` which doesn't exist, and thus gets returned as `0`, resulting in `$0` i.e. the entire input line - which might well be what you mean, but really hairy and only happens to work by a lucky set of catastrophes).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your source array contents are "s=c=g++" and "ipynb=py", then you may be able use bash parameter expansion to build your extension array.

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=("s=c=g++" "ipynb=py")

for i in "${arr[@]}" ; do
    echo "compiler: ${i##*=}"
    ext="${i%=*}"
    read -a ext_arr <<<"${ext//=/ }"
    echo "extensions: ${ext_arr[@]} (array length ${#ext_arr[@]})"
done
```

Output:

```
compiler: g++
extensions: s c (array length 2)
compiler: py
extensions: ipynb (array length 1)
```